# Raw filter with ternary operator for html class attribute

Tags: php, html, css, twig

I've been trying to figure out how to stop Twig escape using the following code, which I feel is a little nicer with the succinct ternary operator.

I hope someone can confirm I'm using the correct syntax and if there are any performance issues doing it like this (as well as alternative methods, if any):

```
<body{{ bodyClass is defined ? (' class="' ~ bodyClass ~ '"')|raw : '' }}>
```

It seems to work and is the only way I've managed to get proper output so far!

An alternative version can be seen here, using string interpolation ([`#{}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation) is my current preferred method):

```
" class=\"#{bodyClass}\""|raw
```

Comment: *"Hoping someone can confirm I'm using the correct syntax"* that makes it sound like you don't know if the code works. Did you mean to ask if it was in the correct style?

Comment: Ah, ok understood. I know `|raw` is the correct function to use, but I've never tried wrapping in parenthesis before (well, not with [string interpolation](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/201/3888) anyway). So yes, I guess correct style would be more appropriate, thanks. Apparently it's [good to go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34257845/838046), but only for non-user editable templates. Twig has some interesting functions and seems like there are a vast many ways to use them!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
<body {{ bodyClass ? class='{bodyClass}'|raw : ''}}>
```

I don't think you need the brackets and tilde signs...